# Conflict cloning public github repository Github - NPM - SSH - not access rights

Tags: git, npm, ssh, openssh

I am trying to use NPM to require a library https://github.com/geckosio/geckos.io. It seems it is downloaded via SSH using a git command but it fails.

My SSH files and config seem to be right:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Lander/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi Lander! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Even I can pull, push, etc:

```
 git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Lander/.ssh/id_rsa':
Already up to date.
```

I am trying to use NPM to require a library, but GIT says I have not the required rights. I suppose it is a publicly readable repository.

```
npm install geckosio/client -save
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/geckosio/client.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

```
git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/geckosio/client.git
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Lander/.ssh/id_rsa':
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please, What am I missing?
Thank you!

=================================== EXTRA 1 ===================================
Testing @SebDieBln, here is the output

```
npm install @geckos.io/client
En línea: 1 Carácter: 13
+ npm install @geckos.io/client
+             ~~~~~~~
El operador de expansión '@' no se puede usar para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión. '@geckos' solamente se puede usar como argumento para un comando. Para hacer referencia a variables en una 
expresión, use '$geckos'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

It is the same problem that the official method gave to me:

```
npm i @geckos.io/client @geckos.io/server
En línea: 1 Carácter: 7
+ npm i @geckos.io/client @geckos.io/server
+       ~~~~~~~
El operador de expansión '@' no se puede usar para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión. '@geckos' solamente se puede usar como argumento para un comando. Para hacer referencia a variables en una 
expresión, use '$geckos'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 25
+ npm i @geckos.io/client @geckos.io/server
+                         ~~~~~~~
El operador de expansión '@' no se puede usar para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión. '@geckos' solamente se puede usar como argumento para un comando. Para hacer referencia a variables en una 
expresión, use '$geckos'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

Am I using too new Node and NPM versions?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Ok, finally solved, the problems were:

- The package data was wrong. I was trying to use that 'construction' because I had problems with the "@". (NPM could had given an error if it is true that the package reference was wrong???)
- Windows was not accepting "@". That is the reason I changed "npm i @geckos.io/client @geckos.io/server" to "npm install geckosio/client -save". (and was done in a bad way)

Thank everybody.

Comment: The dependent package is called [geckos.io/client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@geckos.io/client), not geckosio/client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to fetch the sources of the required package?

Would a

```
npm install @geckos.io/client
```

work for you?

If you really need the sources, be sure to look at the right place: There is no repository `github.com/geckosio/client`. However there seems to be a folder `package/client` in the repo `github.com/geckosio/geckos.io`.

Comment: TY! I have tried it and updated the main post.

Comment: Ok, the problem was Windows! If I put the @xxxxxxx inside double quotes, it works!